# How to extend the first row of a table with the second row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

I am looking for a way to use JS or jQuery to automatically extend the first row of a table with the second row.

For example, I currently have a table in this format:

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And I would like to move the items in the second row into the first row, like this:

```
<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td>Item 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
</table>
```

The second set of `tr` tags does not have to be removed, and can remain blank, if that simplifies the code.

The table will have an id, but not any of the tags inside it.

Comment: This is simple. What have you tried so far? Or were you hoping someone would just do it for you?

Comment: @I Hate Lazy: I saw your other comments. If the answer is simple, you could have just posted it instead of trying to teach me some sort of lesson about trying hard before asking questions. This website is meant for professional collaboration. If you are concerned about people wasting your precious time with questions they could have answered on their own, then I find it interesting that you spent so much time intentionally not helping me and even found the time to judge other people's replies and tell me what not to do. Your degree of experience is never an excuse to act unprofessionally.

Comment: My comments below are more for future readers. With respect to your question, it shows absolutely no effort on your part. For a programmer *that's* what is unprofessional. Yes, I could have posted it, but no I was not willing to encourage this sort of activity on StackOverflow. I can't stop others from answering, so when they do, the least I can do is try to help future readers ***who are actually taking the effort to research a question*** to stay away from poor solutions.

Comment: @chiralcenter in his defense you selected the worst answer, I can understand the frustration...

Comment: @chiralcenter also you might want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I am not a programmer. StackOverflow does not require you to be one to ask questions. I suspect that one of the best parts of this website is connecting experienced professionals with people like me who have little to no experience so please do not make the mistake of holding me to some kind of code of conduct. I went with the first answer that showed up and it worked for me, that is all I wanted. If you all want to have a discussion about what works better, great, but I will take major issue with anyone trying to make some sort of public example of me, when they have absolutely no right.

Comment: @Christophe I am very well aware of the instructions on asking questions. I thoroughly searched StackOverflow for an answer to my question prior to posting it. If an answer already exists and I missed it, I apologize, but as I said before I am new to both this website and this industry so I may have easily overlooked something. Perhaps if you all are so concerned about dispensing your knowledge to someone who is undeserving, you could have pointed me to a source instead.

Comment: @chiralcenter "it worked for me, that is all I wanted" => one of the best part of a forum is when it serves a community, not just an individual.

Comment: Please do not take things out of context. I was not justifying my entire question, I was explaining why I chose the answer that I did, something for which I was criticized several times. This by no means implies that I am ignoring the other answers, even if I did not understand why one answer may be better than another. Like I said, if you feel like having an actual informative discussion about how these different answers vary, I would be more than happy to participate.

Comment: The first answer converts the cells into a string and then back into cells. This is unnecessary, heavier than just moving the cells, and in more advanced scenarios it might break things because you are actually deleting the existing cells in the process. It works in simple cases though, so if you were happy with it I perfectly understand. On my side I upvoted the useful comment and relayed @IHateLazy's frustration, in hope that future readers would weigh alternatives. If you don't understand a comment, you're welcome to ask for more details (well, as you just did).

Comment: @Christophe: Sad thing is that when the chosen solution ends up breaking handlers, data, etc., OP will be back here again, not to learn or improve skills, but just looking for more free coding service.

Comment: @Christophe thank you very much for all your help - both with my question as well as with all of IHateLazy's problems. I appreciate you bearing with me and taking the time to actually give me some constructive answers. Even if I was in the wrong, I am certainly not used to being treated quite so unprofessionally so I apologize for my poor reaction to all of it earlier. In the future, I will make sure to be more sensitive towards these concerns, and especially towards those who tend to get so easily frustrated on their account :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
var row2 = $("#tbl1 tr:eq(1)");
$("#tbl1 tr:first").append(row2.html()); // Add row 2 data to row 1
row2.html("");                           // empty row 2
```

Comment: Why are you generating and parsing HTML instead of simply moving nodes? The DOM is not a string.

Comment: @chiralcenter: Don't use this solution. It's an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
var table=document.getElementById("tbl1"),
    rows=table.rows;
while (rows[1].cells[0]) rows[0].appendChild(rows[1].cells[0]);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7kubW/

You could of course use jQuery, but plain JavaScript is easy to read when working with tables.

Comment: +1 for simple native solution. I had nearly the same thing typed out, but didn't want to post it for someone who hasn't tried anything.

Comment: @IHateLazy I perfectly understand your concerns. I couldn't resist the opportunity to show that jQuery is not always the answer :-)

Comment: Certainly a worthy cause. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
​var $tr2td​ = $('#tbl1 tr:eq(1)').find('td').detach();

$('#tbl1 tr:eq(0)').append($tr2td);​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

### [See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9YGBC/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
​$('#tbl1 td').​​​​​​​​​​unwrap().wrapAll('<tr/>');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DABDa/

Or if it's only row 1 and 2

```
​$('#tbl1 tr').slice(0,2).find('td').unwrap().wrapAll('<tr/>');​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SsTRE/